# Is it possible to set the value of a variable in the immediate window in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am debugging a stored procedure. How do I set the value of a variable in the immediate window inside SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

```
Declare @UserType varchar(20)
```

**ImmediateWindow**

```
set @UserType = 'A';
'set @UserType = 'A';' could not be evaluated
```

Comment: `SELECT @UserType = 'A'`